# TypeScript - No "Variable is used before being assigned" inside a function

Tags: typescript, variables, initialization, undefined, let

I would like to understand the following TypeScript behavior:

The following code

```
let a: number
if (a === undefined) {
    console.log("how?")
}
```

throws an error: "Variable 'a' is used before being assigned.".

But the following code

```
let a: number
const f = (): void => {
    if (a === undefined) {
        console.log("how?")
    }
}
f()
```

works just fine and logs "how?".

Why is that? And also, how come `a === undefined` if its type is `number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30053) about this in the Typescript GitHub project. It's a limitation of typescript's technical design.

From Ryan Cavanaugh, it's

> because we don't inline the flow-control effects of functions

Answer (score 4):

To deal with the error `Variable 'a' is used before being assigned.` the simple solution I think is to declare the variable as *either* `number` *or* `undefined`, instead of just `number`.

```js
let a: number | undefined
```

One other pattern is just to initialize a variable with a value:

```js
let a: number = 0
```

I used that pattern a lot in C# years ago, but I don't personally care for that pattern in JavaScript and prefer what you have of leaving a variable un-set if the conditions to assign it a value are conditional.

Answer (score 1):

For the second question: in TS, variables not initialized are always `undefined`, despite of their type. This is different, for example, from C# where a variable typed `bool` is always true or false and initialized as false. In TS that variable could be also undefined and, if I remember well, also null. So sometimes is good to write

```
if( testVariable === false)
```

instead of simply

```
if( !testVariable )
```

Comment: Thanks. You said "In TS that variable could be also undefined and, if I remember well, also null.", but when I do `let a: number = undefined` I get: `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`. How come?

Comment: Probably (I'm not sure) it can be undefined only before you initialize it with a value. After that you can only assign it a valid typed value. To assign undefined you'll have to defined the variable as `number | undefined`